# Autocomplete Directive in AngularJS not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hello I have created one autocomplete directive in AngularJS which works perfectly fine with 1.8.22 version of Jquery. But when I upgrade the Jquery UI version to 1.11.1 then it had stopped working.

Can anyone please let me know if anything has been stripped out from the new

```
module.directive('autocomplete', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                var items = scope.$eval(attrs.autocomplete);

                if (items !== undefined) {
                    $(element).autocomplete({
                        source: items,
                        select: function (ui, item) {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(item.item.label);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (attrs.autocomplete.indexOf('[') < 0) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.autocomplete, function (value) {
                        $(element).autocomplete({
                            source: value,
                            select: function (ui, item) {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(item.item.label);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript error?

Comment: No errors on the console.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the jquery autocomplete plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/ui.autocomplete/

Comment: I am using the latest jquery-ui-1.11.1.js which already includes autocomplete

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle for this?

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Why dont you use the Typeahead directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. Save you lots of headaches